# Export struct to .csv

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, octave

In Octave I have a large "struct" called "semi_firm" with 19 "rows" (my language might be completely wrong and confusing, believe me it's more confusing for me than for you :) and dimension 1x1. (I'm thinking about this the way I imagine it looks in Excel, so why something massive has a 1x1 dimension is completely beyond me). Some cells in the structure contain a single value, some contain multiple.

I extract the following:

```
out = struct("pnum", semi_firm.Patent_Number, "class", semi_firm.Class, "sub", semi_firm.Subclass)
```

`out` becomes a 1x108033 structure. This should contain three rows and 108033 columns with in each cell exactly one value. I don't understand why it's a 1x108033 structure. After some Googling I convert that structure to a cell:

```
c = struct2cell(out)
```

`c` has dimension 3x1x108033

I want to export this to a .csv file. I tried all variations of [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378996/export-cell-array-to-multi-column-csv-file) but none work because the example has two dimensions while here it has three.

All I want is to turn `c` or `out` into a simple .csv file with ideally three columns (`pnum`, `class`, `sub`) and 108,033 rows with each cell containing one value. Ideally the solution would be expandable to the situation where a single cell contains multiple values. E.g. in semi_firm, there is a "row" called "inventors". There are often multiple inventors per patent.

Following the first comment, some extra information:

I think `squeeze` solves part of my problem but I still get errors when exporting stuff. Here is what I did (bad workaround):

```
pats = c(1,1,1) % dim 1x1
classes = c(2,1,1) % dim 1x1
subs = c(3,1,1) % dim 1x1x108033
csvwrite("pats.csv",cell2mat(pats')')
csvwrite("class.csv", cell2mat(classes')')
```

This works. When I create `subs = c(3,1,1)` it gives me a 1x1x108033 cell. Then I use `subs = squeeze(subs)` and it becomes a 108033x1 cell. Then any variation I use of `csvwrite("subs.csv", cell2mat(subs))` gives me errors.

The problem seems to be that `subs` and `out.sub` contains a seven digit number and every digit is stored as a different value. Exporting it to .csv then creates a distortion. So I need to change the format in which that is stored to be able to export it.

Comment: Haven't understood all your post, but you can use "squeeze(c)" to get rid of the singleton dimension

Comment: Thanks that helps for sure, I think I managed to better define the problem. Hope you can help!

Comment: HI , if you have done `squeeze(c)` (by @gregswiss), the new size should be in 2 dimension; which `size(squeeze(c))` should return `3   108033`. 
In that case you can use the suggested [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378996/export-cell-array-to-multi-column-csv-file)  to proceed with exporting into a .csv file

Comment: the reason your struct has dimensions 1x1, is because it's a scalar (single) struct. Note that like everything else in Octave, your struct can be an array of structs. And when you say that your struct has19 "rows", I guess that you mean that it has 19 fields. Your question is very confusing and shows a bad understanding of basic Octave. You should at the very least read the manual chapter on [data structures](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Data-Containers.html)