# MATLAB export data stored in a double array and cell array to a CSV file

Tags: excel, matlab, csv

I have a MATLAB structure with 19 fields. The main field is a 1 x 108033 double with all values numeric. It looks like this, basically 108033 numbers:

```
pnum: 5384940 5437561 5570271 5661637 5771155   ...
```

I have another field called `inventors` which is a 1 x 108033 cell value. Every cell contains a different number of strings. Columns 1 to 5 for example are

```
inventors:  {2x1 cell}    {4x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}
```

For the first column value, the 2 x 1 cell consists of the following values
`5012491-01` and `2035147-03` and so on.

I'd like to jointly export these two to a CSV file. The ideal outcome would repeat the number in `pnum` so that it establishes a clear link between the `pnum` and the `inventors`. Thus, the ideal outcome would look something like this (with the contents of what is in the `inventors` cell displayed).

```
pnum    inventors
5384940 5012491-01
5384940 2035147-03
5437561 5437561-01
5437561 5437561-02
5437561 5437561-03
5437561 5012491-02
5570271 5437561-03
5661637 1885634-08
5771155 5012491-01
```

I asked a more complex version of this question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093410/export-struct-to-csv) but it was not clear enough what the problem was. Hope it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming each cell in `inventors` is a cell array of strings.  It wouldn't make sense for these to be actual floating point or intenger numbers, because the dash would subtract the two numbers separating them together.  Now, because you're writing to a CSV file, the easiest thing I can think of is to iterate over each number and cell, then repeat the ID number for as many times as there are elements in a cell.  First create the right headers, then write your results.  Something like this comes to mind:

```
f = fopen('data.csv', 'w'); %// Open up data for writing
fprintf(f, 'pnum,inventors\n'); %// Write headers
for ii = 1 : numel(pnum) %// For each unique number
    inventor = inventors{ii};
    for jj = 1 : numel(inventor) %// For each inventor ID
        fprintf(f, '%d,%s\n', pnum(ii), inventor{jj}); %// Write the right combo to file
    end
end
fclose(f); %// Close the file
```

[`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) here opens up a file called `data.csv` so we can write things to it.  What is returned is a file pointer called `f`, which we use to write stuff to this file.  After, we write the headers of the file, consisting of `pnum` and `inventors`.  This is a CSV file so there's a comma separating the two.  Now, for each unique number, we then access the right slot in `inventors` then for each unique inventor, add the same unique ID with the right inventor ID as a line in this file.  I use [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to write things to file using the associated file pointer established earlier.  Once we're done, close the file with [`fclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html).

---

To double check that this works, I've used the small example you've provided in your post:

```
pnum = [5384940 5437561 5570271 5661637 5771155];

inventors = {{'5012491-01', '2035147-03'}.', {'5437561-01', '5437561-02', '5437561-03', '5012491-02'}.', {'5437561-03'}, {'1885634-08'}, {'5012491-01'}};
```

Bear in mind that I don't have access to your `struct`, so you'll have to access the right fields and assign them to the corresponding variables seen above.  So if your `struct` is called something like `data`, then you'd do this before you run the above code:

```
pnum = data.pnum;
inventors = data.inventors;
```

Running the above code I just wrote and opening up the CSV file (which is called `data.csv`), I get this:

```
pnum,inventors
5384940,5012491-01
5384940,2035147-03
5437561,5437561-01
5437561,5437561-02
5437561,5437561-03
5437561,5012491-02
5570271,5437561-03
5661637,1885634-08
5771155,5012491-01
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly for my entirely sample as well. Thanks so much man, now I can continue to work on this in R, which is more my language :) .

Comment: Fantastic! Let me know if you need anything else. If not, consider accepting my answer to let the StackOverflow community know you no longer need help in this question. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry completely forgot about that :) Done!